# How can DataSource be a reference to a ConnectionPoolDataSource.

Tags: java, jdbc

The preferred way of obtaining a connection is through a DataSource from what I have read. There are different interfaces such as `DataSource` and `ConnectionPoolDataSource`. Let say we use PostgreSQL driver and want to use connection pooling on a Glassfish server.

In your application code you invoke `getConnection()` on a property of type `DataSource`. How is this possible? Haven't Glassfish created a datasource of type `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (or more correctly an implementing class) and bound it to a JNDI name and when you get a datasource by using the JNDI name you get an object of `ConnectionPoolDataSource` not `DataSource`?? `ConnectionPoolDataSource` does not have a `getConnection()` method. I don't understand this server magic.

Could someone explain how all this fits together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), [`Driver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) or [`ConnectionPoolDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html) that you can select in the Glassfish config is not exposed to your application directly, instead the Application Server has its own `DataSource` that maintains a connection pool, this datasource uses the configured `DataSource`, `Driver` or `ConnectionPoolDataSource` as the factory for the connections it will keep in its pool.

So when you configure Glassfish with a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`, it uses the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` to create the physical connections ([`PooledConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html) objects) for a connection pool. This connection pool is kept by the application server `DataSource` implementation. Your application then access that connection pool using this `DataSource`. The DataSource hands out logical `Connection` objects from the connection pool.

The exact inner workings of a logical and physical connection are implementation dependent, but these logical connections are usually some kind of proxy or wrapper around the physical connection. When you obtain the logical connection, the physical connection is checked out from the connection pool. When you close the logical connection, the connection pool receives a signal that the physical connection is available again and returns it to the connection pool.

Comment: So inside Glassfish (or another app server) in the case of connection pooling there is an instance of a ConnectionPoolDataSource, but this is not exposed? It is used internally?

Comment: That is not what it says in my answer. A connection pool as provided by an applicationserver is a normal `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation. It can use a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` implementation (eg from a specific vendor implementation) to get the actual physical connections to the database.

Comment: Basically `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` is badly named: it is not a connection pool; it is meant to be used by a connection pool.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I wrote the question wrong. I know now that the ConnectionPoolDataSource is not a pool but it can provide PooledConnnections. The app server creates and maintains the pool, but it must create an instance of the implementation of a ConnectionPoolDataSource from the driver if you choose that in the dropdown box? If you choose a regular data source in the drop down box then it use just a simple data source without creating a pool right? Thank you for helping me. Please explain more

Comment: As far as I know, in both cases it will maintain a connection pool, the only difference is how it obtains and maintains the physical connections.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer provides many answer to my question. So in a bird eye recap: The applications look at app servers as a data source (it have a DataSource implementation) and the app server will do pooling etc behind the scenes?